# Non-point spectrum of involution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $B$ is a Banach space and $T:B\rightarrow B$ is a linear map that satisfies $T^2=I$. Is it possible for $T$ to have non-empty continuous or residual spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If $T^2=I$, you have $\sigma(T)\subset \{-1,1\}$: since 
$$
(T+\lambda)(T-\lambda)=(T-\lambda)(T+\lambda)=T^2-\lambda^2 I=(1-\lambda^2)I,
$$
we get that for any $\lambda\neq\pm1$, $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.

Note that $$ (T+I)-(T-I)=2I,$$ which implies $$B=(T+I)B+(T-I)B.$$

All the elements of $(T+I)B$ are eigenvectors for $1$, and all elements of $(T-I)B$ are eigenvectors for $-1$.

If one of these spaces were $\{0\}$, say $(T+I)B=0$, we get $T=-I$ and then $\sigma(T)=\{-1\}$ and it is an eigenvalue. Similarly, if $(T-I)B=0$, then $T=I$.

Comment: I understand that $\pm 1$ are the only possible eigenvalues, by this argument; but what allows one to know that there can't be other values in the spectrum?

Comment: It follows from the spectral mapping theorem, but in this case it can be shown explicitly in one line. I have added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $T^2=I$, then the resolvent of $T$ exists for $\lambda\ne \pm 1$ and is given by
$$
       (T-\lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}(T+\lambda I)
$$
You can verify this directly:
$$
     \frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}(T+\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)=\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}(T^2-\lambda^2I)=I.
$$
So the spectrum of $T$ is contained in $\{-1,1\}$ and any such point in the spectrum must be an eigenvalue because $(T+I)(T-I)=0=(T-I)(T+I)$.

Comment: I think this answers the question when the condition imposed is $T^2 = T$, rather than $T^2 = I$. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ougoah : I changed it for you. The technique really only depends on having an annihilating polynomial.

Comment: ($\pm 1$, right?)

Comment: @ougoah : Yes, left-over from the previous one that I corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Can something similar to be done for any polynomial, in place of $x^2 - 1$?

Comment: @ougoah : Yes, it works for any annihilating polynomial $p$. The resolvent is constructible.